# Powerpoint VBA actively select slide range based on string in textbox

Tags: vba, powerpoint, selection, slide

I want to scan thorough a slide deck for text boxes containing a search string and leave the active presentation with Active selected slides.

*** I can search ok...>> Creating a list of slides with my text on

```
Function FindSlidesWithText(ByVal Owner As String) As String
Dim oSl As Slide
    Dim oShp As Shape
    Dim strSearch As String
    Dim i As Integer
    Dim slideList As String

    If Owner = "" Then
        strSearch = InputBox("Enter the text to search for:")
    Else
        strSearch = Owner
    End If
    
       
    Dim SomeoneSlides As String
    SomeoneSlides = ""

    SomeoneSlides = ""
    For Each oSl In ActivePresentation.Slides
        For Each oShp In oSl.Shapes
            If oShp.HasTextFrame Then
                If InStr(1, oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text, strSearch, vbTextCompare) > 0 Then
                    slideList = slideList & "Slide " & oSl.SlideNumber & ": " & oShp.TextFrame.TextRange.Text & vbCrLf
                    SomeoneSlides = SomeoneSlides & oSl.SlideNumber & ","
                End If
            End If
        Next
    Next

    'we now have "search" unique slides.
    MsgBox slideList
End Function
```

*** I note the following works as I want - leaving my in power points seeing highlight boxes around the slides 1,2,5

```
Dim r1 As SlideRange
Set r1 = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(1,2, 5)) 'this works
r1.Select
```

*** However, when i try to create this programmatically i fail (only highlighting the last slide in the array)

```
'Call SelectSlides("1,2,") '(output from the search)


    Sub SelectSlides(YourSlideList As String)
        Dim slideArr() As String
        'Dim slideNum As Integer
        Dim selAry As String
    
      ActiveWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewNormal
        ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
       
        slideArr = Split(YourSlideList, ",")
    
        Dim r1 As SlideRange
        For i = 0 To (UBound(slideArr) - 1)
            slideNum = CInt(slideArr(i))
            selAry = selAry & slideNum
            
            'For all slides selected - modify as needed....
            With ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(slideNum)
                'Ignore the default background settings.
                .FollowMasterBackground = False
                'And add a new background color and effect.
                .Background.Fill.PresetGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1, msoGradientDaybreak
            End With
            
            Set r1 = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(Array(slideNum)) 'this works
        
        Next
        r1.Select
        
    End Sub
```

'///this is now working

```
Sub SelectSlides(YourSlideList As String)
    Dim slideArr() As String
    'Dim slideNum As Integer
    Dim selAry As String
    Dim selAry2(99) As Long

    ActiveWindow.ViewType = PpViewType.ppViewNormal
    ActiveWindow.Panes(1).Activate
   
    slideArr = Split(YourSlideList, ",")
   ' slideArr2() = Split(YourSlideList, ",")
    
    For i = 0 To (UBound(slideArr) - 1)
        slideNum = CInt(slideArr(i))
        selAry = selAry & slideNum
        selAry2(i) = slideNum
        'For all slides selected - modify as needed....
        With ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(slideNum)
            'Ignore the default background settings.
            .FollowMasterBackground = False
            'And add a new background color and effect.
            .Background.Fill.PresetGradient msoGradientHorizontal, 1, msoGradientDaybreak
        End With
        
    Next
    
    Dim r1 As SlideRange
    Set r1 = ActivePresentation.Slides.Range(selAry2)
    r1.Select
    
End Sub
```

Comment: think i have it....now

Comment: Move your response to answer your own question.